# Rails: A Rating Up or Down Counter Part II

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, counter, rating

*Basic Gist*:
I am currently trying to create a rating counter that has a up or down feature to it. I create d a separate model to show the rating counter and the counter belongs to the post. I am trying to create something along the lines of Reddit or even Stackoverflow's. I am currently stuck on what to do. Thank you everyone.

*DB:Rating Table*: post_id, user_id, ratings

*DB:Post Table*: ratings_count

**Rating Model**

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :post_id, :user_id, :ratings
  has_many :post
  has_many :users

  validates :post_id, presence: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

**Post Model**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :ratings_count
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :ratings

  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :smiles, presence: true
end
```

**Rating Controller**

```
Nothing in it
```

**Post Controller**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def rate
    @post = post.find(params[:id])
    if params[:ratings_count]
      @post.ratings_count=@post.ratings_count+1
    end
  end

  def unrate

    unsure

  end
end
```

**Rating Form**

```
<%=form_for @post, :action=>"rate" do |f|%>
<%= f.hidden_field :ratings_count %>
<%=f.submit "Rate"%>
<%end%>
```

Comment: Potentially related reading: http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:
http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M000348

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def rate
    Post.increment_counter(:ratings_count, params[:id]) if params[:ratings_count]
  end

  def unrate
    # You will obviously need to check for a ratings_down or something similar field in your form
    Post.decrement_counter(:ratings_count, params[:id]) if params[:ratings_count]
  end
end
```

Comment: I am unsure if I setup the form correctly? can you verify? and Thank you

Comment: No it is just not incrementing

Comment: Are you submitting this form via ajax? If so, watch your console in either Firebug for Firefox or the default one in Chrome

Comment: No ajax but hmm, on my ratings model, the rating integer, post_id and user_id is not getting filled in, is there something that is missing? Because the def rate is only incrementing the ratings_count in the post model

Comment: Also, in your Rating model change `has_many :post` to `has_many :posts`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8041/discussion-between-brian-kim-and-dennismonsewicz)

Comment: Thank you for that catch, mmm, sorry for so many questions still somewhat new to rails, mmm is the rating model suppose to be filled in from just the form based off the def rate? And I noticed that it did one thing which was rate the post that has the same id as the user even though a different post id was selected.